# Getting Null Pointer on Spring dataSource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, datasource

I want data source instance but I am getting NPE.

xml :

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.jms" />
    <context:annotation-config />    

    <!--DataSource Bean Initialization-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nl"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="pwd"/>
    </bean>
```

main method :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");

        Schedule s = new Schedule();
        s.call();
    }
}
```

schedule class :

```
public class Schedule {
    LoginLog l = new LoginLog();
    public void call(){
        System.out.println("In SC");
        l.loginEventLogging();
    }
}
```

LoginLog :

```
@Service
public class LoginLog{

    @Autowired
    private IMailEvent mailEvent;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void loginEventLogging(){
        System.out.println("In Log");
        String checkoutSql = "select *  from transaction where data_date::date = current_date;";
        System.out.println("HERE");
        System.out.println("KKK" + dataSource);
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate template = new org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate(dataSource);        
    }
}
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:169)
    at ngl.jms.dbLog.LoginLog.loginEventLogging(LoginLog.java:30)
    at ngl.jms.dbLog.Schedule.call(Schedule.java:13)
    at ngl.jms.application.Main.main(Main.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I don't understand why it gives me an error NPE.
Help.

Comment: do you have required postgres library in path?

Comment: yes I have added maven.

Comment: You are not supposed to create the class using the "new" operator. Instead you should get it form the spring context.

Comment: @sinisa229mihajlovski -then what I ve to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are instantiating `LoginLog` on your own

(see `LoginLog l = new LoginLog();` in `Schedule`).

That means that `LoginLog` is not managed by Spring and therefor no dependency injection will occur .

What you need to do is the following (will result in all the relevant classes being managed by Spring):

```
@Component
public class Schedule {
    @Autowired
    private LoginLog l;

    public void call(){
        System.out.println("In SC");
        l.loginEventLogging();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");

        Schedule s = context.getBean(Schedule.class)
        s.call();
    }
}
```

Comment: then what should I have to do sir ?

Comment: Still not working this code sir, what are you told about schedule ?

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ Check my updated answer. I have added all the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Schedule and LoginLog are under package "nl.jms" or any of the sub packages:
You should change:

```
@Component    
public class Schedule {
    @Autowired
    private LoginLog l;
    public void call(){
        System.out.println("In SC");
        l.loginEventLogging();
    }
}
```

And then in the main method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");

        Schedule s = applicationContext.getBean(Schedule.class.getName());
        s.call();
    }
}
```

This way spring context knows what you try to do, and will do the wiring for you.